# How can we install civicrm extension which is not available for drupal

Tags: civicrm-home

I want to add civi hr extension to drupal. But is not available in drupal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to first get into the extension directory, and download the extension directly. Then you can install the extension from Manage Extension Page.

```
wget https://github.com/civicrm/civihr/archive/1.3.0.zip
unzip 1.3.0.zip
mv civihr-1.3.0 civihr
```

You can now move to `Administer>System Settings>Manage Extensions` Install CiviHR and you are good to go.

This [link](https://github.com/civicrm/civihr/blob/1.3.0/doc/INSTALL.md) can help you further.